# Trouble with pointers and functions in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, pointers

I have a function like this:

```
void getSprite(string *spriteLines[SPRITE_YSIZE]);
```

And then I have a calling to the function like this:

```
int main() {
    string *spriteLines[SPRITE_YSIZE];
    getSprite(spriteLines);
```

By here, everything OK. But I decided to declare spriteLines as a string instead of a pointer so I changed the code to this:

```
int main() {
    string spriteLines[SPRITE_YSIZE];
    getSprite(&spriteLines);
```

And an error shows up:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string (*)[5] {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)[5]}’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string** {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>**}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void getSprite(std::__cxx11::string**)’ getSprite(&spriteLines);
```

Do someone of you knows why? I can't understand this.

Extra data: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen v1 and GNU G++.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Explaining the error message is the easy part. Your intentions are a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you declared an array of string pointers. In the second example you declared an array of strings.  Both arrays are passed your function as a pointer.  Your error occurs because the are different "types".

In the second example you would need to change your getSprite function to:

void getSprite(string spriteLines[SPRITE_YSIZE])